# Java unboxing on method return value

Tags: java, unboxing

Given following method:

```
Long getLong() {
    ...
}
```

If I call it and assign the return value to a variable like this:

```
long abc = getLong();
```

Will a `Long` object get generated and then converted to long or Java is smart enough to avoid generating the intermediate `Long` object? Or it might actually depends on the implementation of `getLong()`?

The reason I am asking this is that the wrapper object size is usually much bigger than the corresponding primitive type size. If I have to call this method a lot of times and each time memory needs to be allocated to the `Long` object, the program will end up consuming a lot more memory than it actually needs, which triggers more GC cycles.

Also, how can I verify the exactly steps happening when executing `long abc = getLong()` (basically also looking for guidance on how can I get answers myself for the questions above)?

Comment: The method returns an object, the local assignment causes the unboxing.

Comment: The wrapper type will be generated and unboxed to a `long`. See [JLS-5.1.8. Unboxing Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8). The relevant part says *If `r` is a reference of type `Long`, then unboxing conversion converts `r` into `r.longValue()`*

Comment: I would suggest you to return the value inside `getLong` as `Long.valueOf(someValue)`, this would try to take the Long object from cache instead of creating a new object. Also the `new Long` is now deprecated.

Comment: "how can I verify the exactly steps happening when executing `long abc = getLong()`" How about inspecting the compiled bytecode?

Comment: @GauthamM could you elaborate a little bit more on this cache thing? What is cached?

Comment: @Z.SP If you look at the source code for `Long.valueOf`, then you could see that the values in the range [-128,127] are returned from the cache.

Comment: The real question is why are you using `Long` in the first place? Use `long`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps the simplest way to test your question is by writing a small example and then run the Java disassembler.

Let's say we had this class:

```java
public class Unboxing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long l = getLong();
    }

    public static Long getLong() {
        return 10L;
    }

}
```

Then we can compile it (`javac Unboxing.java`) and once compiled we can disassemble it (`javap -c -s Unboxing`) to see its bytecodes and learn what the JVM is doing under the hood.

```
public class Unboxing {
  public Unboxing();
    descriptor: ()V
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    descriptor: ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
    Code:
       0: invokestatic  #7                  // Method getLong:()Ljava/lang/Long;
       3: invokevirtual #13                 // Method java/lang/Long.longValue:()J
       6: lstore_1
       7: return

  public static java.lang.Long getLong();
    descriptor: ()Ljava/lang/Long;
    Code:
       0: ldc2_w        #19                 // long 10l
       3: invokestatic  #21                 // Method java/lang/Long.valueOf:(J)Ljava/lang/Long;
       6: areturn
}
```

You can see in the code that it gets an `Long` object, and then call its `longValue` method on it:

```
0: invokestatic  #7                  // Method getLong:()Ljava/lang/Long;
3: invokevirtual #13                 // Method java/lang/Long.longValue:()J
```

After that it stores it into the variable `l` (`lstore_1`).

So, that probably answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

You asked: *"Will a Long object get generated and then converted to long or Java is smart enough to avoid generating the intermediate Long object? Or it might actually depends on the implementation of getLong()?"*

Java is smart enough to protect you from shooting your own foot, so it will create a Long object, just as it is requested by the method signature, then if your code assigns it to a `long` it will unbox it. Whichever reason the developer had to return `Long` from `getLong()` must be strictly respected. Boxing/Unboxing is focused on readability and not on performance. It is strictly required to create a new `long getLong()` method if you want to only use `long` all along your code, which will usually be faster.

For the other question, you just need to use a debugger and use the **"step into"** tools provided by the debugger, try with Eclipse, IntelliJ or NetBeans, to name a few

Answer (score 0):

By all probability you have no need or reason to care.

Yes, as the others say, when a method returns a `Long` object, then it returns a `Long` object. Or `null`, but that doesn’t seem to be the case here. However, if that object is created in the method just before return, then it’s a very short-lived object. The garbage collector handles such efficiently, so allocation of the space is unlikely to hurt you. You will not end up with any considerable memory consumption since you have got only one (1) `Long` object at a time.

In the case in Edwin Dalorzo’s answer and many other cases the `Long` object will not even be allocated and garbage collected at all and will not require any more memory than the primitive `long`. How come? `Long` objects for the range from -127 through 128 are pre-allocated and shared. So when Edwin’s method returns `10L`, in practice a reference to the pre-allocated object is just returned. No allocation takes place at return.

That said, if the method never returns `null`, for readability reasons returning an object is a bad design. It should return a primitive. If in some cases there is no long value to return, one may consider returning an `OptionalLong`. Those are not pre-allocated, but are also short-lived and therefore handled efficiently by the garbage collector.